# How to make Edge extension visible to all user?

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

My case is that, to install an Edge extension, and make it available for all the users.
But, the extension I installed is not visible to other user. Is there any setting to configured it for all users(local account)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out provisioned apps, which can help you automatically install the extension for new users.

See "Sideload the app for all users" section in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx for more details.